# I need VBA query regarding "Find" and "Replace"

Tags: vba, replace

I need VBA query regarding `"Find"` and `"Replace"`

- In word document i need to do changes words based on Defined excel sheet Dictionary (Excel sheet Name: Pardu)
  Excel Sheet location: `"D:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\Pardu.xlsx"`

Example: In word document pre-defined word `'Goodboy'`(A2 cell word) should change as `'Good Boy'` (B2 cell word)

like that..Based on A and B columns i need to replace all `'Column A words'` as `'Column B words'`

```
A1= NATIVE  REPLACE B1
A2= Goodboy Good Boy    B2
A3= Hw ar you   How are you?    B3
A4= Paardu  Pardu   B4
A5= :',.lk  kqwljn  B5
```

Pls send Query to: mynameispardu@gmail.com

Thank You,
Pardu.

Answer (score 0):

need exact vba query like the below..

```
Sub Pardu()
'
' Pardu Macro
'
Sub Main()
Dim xl As Object 'Excel.Application
Dim wb As Object 'Excel.Workbook
Dim ws As Object 'Excel.Worksheet
Dim rng As Object 'Excel.Range
Dim cl As Object  'Excel.Range
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("D:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\Pardu.xlsx") '## Modify as needed
Set ws = wb.Sheets(1) '##Modify as needed
Set rng = ws.Range("A2", ws.Range("B2").End(xlDown))
For Each cl In rng
    Call Macro5(cl.Value, cl.Offset(0, 1).Value)
Next
End Sub
```